# Searching the contacts database for a name without case sensitivity

Tags: android

I have this cursor right here that searches the contacts database:

```
String name_to_search = edittext.getText().toString();    
String select = "(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " == \"" +name_to_search+ "\" )";
                        Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
                        this.startManagingCursor(c);
```

But if the name in the edittext is `john smith`  and the name in the contacts DB is `John Smith` I don't get any results.

How do I make the cursor not check for case sensitivity?

Comment: Have you tried: `String select = "(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " == \"" +name_to_search+ "\" COLLATE NOCASE)";`?

Comment: Thank you. I was adding "COLLATE NOCASE" to the cursor instead. If you answer the question I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS support function UPPER(), you can do something like this:

```
String name_to_search = edittext.getText().toString().toUpperCase();    
String select = "(UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") == \"" +name_to_search+ "\" )";
                            Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
                            this.startManagingCursor(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public String[]  fetechRatio()//Search from database table WITH WHERE CONDITION
{
    mDb= mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{mHelper.COL_VALUE};
    Cursor cursor=mDb.rawQuery("SELECT "+mHelper.COL_VALUE+" FROM " +mHelper.Table_Name + " WHERE " + mHelper.COL_HEAD + " = '" + alphbet + "' ORDER BY " + mHelper.COL_HEAD + " ", null);
    String name[] =new String[cursor.getCount()];
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    value=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mHelper.COL_VALUE));
    return name;
}
```

Just use like this ..your condition.